# Weird dimensions when trying to write a FITS BinaryTable (or AsciiTable) in Java

Tags: java, fits

This first function is stolen directly from the nom-tam-fits site: https://nom-tam-fits.github.io/nom-tam-fits/intro.html

```
private static void dataTableToBinaryFitsDummy() throws Exception {
    BufferedFile bf = new BufferedFile("table.fits", "rw");

     BasicHDU.getDummyHDU().write(bf);  // Write an initial null HDU

     double[] ra = {1.};
     double[] dec = {2.};
     String[] name = {"          "}; // maximum length will be 10 characters

     Object[] row = {ra, dec, name};
     long rowSize = ArrayFuncs.computeLSize(row);

     BinaryTable table = new BinaryTable();

     table.addRow(row);

     Header header = new Header();
     table.fillHeader(header);

     BinaryTableHDU bhdu = new BinaryTableHDU(header, table);

     bhdu.setColumnName(0, "ra", null);
     bhdu.setColumnName(1, "dec", null);
     bhdu.setColumnName(2, "name", null);

     bhdu.getHeader().setNaxis(2, 1000);  // set the header to the actual number of rows we write
     bhdu.getHeader().write(bf);

     ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) rowSize);

     for (int event = 0; event < 1000; event ++){
         buffer.clear();

         // update ra, dec and name here

         buffer.putDouble(event);
         buffer.putDouble(dec[0]);
         buffer.put(("event "+event).getBytes());

         buffer.flip();
         bf.write(buffer.array());
     }

     FitsUtil.pad(bf, rowSize * 1000);
     bf.close();
}
```

As a starting point, I want to be able to pass in an arbitrary collection of primitive double arrays.  This was my attempt, which IMO shouldn't be particularly different from the original.

```
private static void dataTableToBinaryFitsDummyWithArgsDoublesOnlyWrapper() {
    int nRows = 100;
    
    double [] rowA = new double[nRows];
    double [] rowB = new double[nRows];
    double [] rowC = new double[nRows];
    double [] rowD = new double[nRows];
    
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i=0;i<nRows;i++) {
        rowA[i] = i;
        rowB[i] = 2*i;
        rowC[i] = random.nextGaussian();
        rowD[i] = rowC[i] * -1;
    }
    
    ImmutableList<double[]> columns = ImmutableList.of(rowA, rowB, rowC, rowD);
    ImmutableList<String> names = ImmutableList.of("ints", "double ints", "randos", "neg randos");
    
    try {
        dataTableToBinaryFitsDummyWithArgsDoublesOnly(columns, names, 4, nRows);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
private static void dataTableToBinaryFitsDummyWithArgsDoublesOnly(ImmutableList<double[]> columns,
        ImmutableList<String> names, int nCols, int nRows) throws Exception {
    BufferedFile bf = new BufferedFile("tableWithArgs.fits", "rw");

     BasicHDU.getDummyHDU().write(bf);  // Write an initial null HDU
     Object[] row = new Object[nCols];
     for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
         row[i] = columns.get(i);
     }
     long rowSize = ArrayFuncs.computeLSize(row);
     
     BinaryTable table = new BinaryTable();
     table.addRow(row);
     
     Header header = new Header();
     table.fillHeader(header);
     
     BinaryTableHDU bhdu = new BinaryTableHDU(header, table);
     
     for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
         bhdu.setColumnName(i, names.get(i), null);
     }
     
     bhdu.getHeader().setNaxis(2, nRows);
     bhdu.getHeader().write(bf);
     
     ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) rowSize);

     for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i ++){
         buffer.clear();

         // update ra, dec and name here

         for (double[] column : columns) {
             buffer.putDouble(column[i]);
         }
         
         buffer.flip();
         bf.write(buffer.array());
     }

     FitsUtil.pad(bf, rowSize * nRows);
     bf.close();
}
```

However, what I get looks very different.  I want the rows to look like

```
ints, double ints, randos, neg randos
0.0, 0.0, 0.66938, -0.66938
1.0, 2.0, 0.53482, -0.53482
2.0, 4.0, 0.66825, -0.66825
...
```

But instead I get

```
ints, double ints, randos, neg randos
(0.0, 0.0, 0.66938, -0.66938, ...), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...)
(1.0, 2.0, 0.53482, -0.53482, ...), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...)
```

It looks like instead of getting 4 columns and 100 rows of numbers, I'm getting 4 columns and 100 rows of 100-number lists.  I followed the canonical example as best I could, why did this happen?

While I'm at it, I also want this to be an AsciiTable and AsciiTableHDU, but the only examples I'm seeing are with BinaryTables, BinaryTableHDUs and ByteBuffers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with `nom.tam.fits`, but according to the docs [BinaryTable.addRow](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/heasarc/fits/java/v1.0/javadoc/nom/tam/fits/BinaryTable.html#addRow-java.lang.Object:A-) takes an array of arrays of primitives (this is because the data in a single cell of a FITS binary table can itself be a multi-dimensional array).

That's why the original example you cited creates an row from an array of 1-element arrays:

```java
     double[] ra = {1.};
     double[] dec = {2.};
     String[] name = {"          "}; // maximum length will be 10 characters

     Object[] row = {ra, dec, name};
```

In your code you seem to be confusing rows and columns:

```java
    double [] rowA = new double[nRows];
    double [] rowB = new double[nRows];
    double [] rowC = new double[nRows];
    double [] rowD = new double[nRows];
```

Here, each of these arrays represents a full *column* of data (which is why their lengths are `nRows`).

Then here

```java
     Object[] row = new Object[nCols];
     for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
         row[i] = columns.get(i);
     }
```

you create a single "row" containing for the values in that row the *entire* columns.  You are missing some outer for-loop over `nRows`.

There is also a [`BinaryTable.addColumn`](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/heasarc/fits/java/v1.0/javadoc/nom/tam/fits/BinaryTable.html#addColumn-java.lang.Object-) which should probably more efficient for adding entire columns at once (especially if you pre-specify the number and types of columns).

The main use case of the original example, where one row is being written at a time, might be if you have some long-running observation or event logging process where one row is appended to the table at a time in a streaming fashion.